# How to fix the Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, max, function-definition

I'm writing a program to find the largest number of an array using recursion. The returns a segmentation fault. I did some research on it. It turns out that there is something with accessing the array out of the given length. I don't know how to fix this error. More specifically, I don't know how to set a parameter that allows an array in a specific user-provided length. Also I don't know how to represent the argument of it.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findLargest(int, int[]);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Input %d elements in the array: \n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("element - %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Largest element of an array is: %d", findLargest(n, arr));
}

int findLargest(int n, int arr[]) {
    static int i = 0;
    int x = -9999999;
    if (i < n) {
        if (arr[i] > x)
            x = arr[i];
        printf("%d\n", i);
        ++i;
    }
    findLargest(n, arr);
}
```

Comment: 1. I'd use INT_MIN (include limits.h) instead of -999999 2. your function findLargest() never returns - it should have some return statements. I leave it for your homework to place them properly.

Comment: Your findLargest function is recursive and there is no base condition to exit from the recursive function so its calling the function again and again and causes segmentation fault.

Comment: Isn't ```(i <n)``` the base condition? As the user will specify the length (```n```). The recursion will loop until i < n.

Comment: Also, I've add the return statement now. Thanks @ivan.ukr

Comment: Re "*Isn't (i <n) the base condition?*", Even when `i<n`, `findLargest` is still called recursively. Maybe it's *supposed* to be the base condition, but it isn't.

Comment: Put away work on this and learn how to use a debugger to step through code. Being able to do that will allow you to quickly fix lots of different problems, including that one. There are video tutorials available online, pick one for your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition

```
int findLargest(int n, int arr[]) {
    static int i = 0;
    int x = -9999999;
    if (i < n) {
        if (arr[i] > x)
            x = arr[i];
        printf("%d\n", i);
        ++i;
    }
    findLargest(n, arr);
}
```

does not make a sense.

For example the user can pass for the first parameter a non-positive number.
Secondly the array can contain values that are less than the magic number `-9999999`.

This assignment

```
x = arr[i];
```

does not have an effect because in each recursive call of the function the variable `x` is initialized anew by the value `-9999999`

```
int x = -9999999;
```

Also as the static variable `i` is initialized only once

```
static int i = 0;
```

then calling the function a second time results in undefined behavior because the variable is not reset.

And more importantly the function does not have a return statement.

The function should be declared like

```
size_t findLargest( const int a[], size_t n );
```

that is the first parameter shall have the qualifier `const` and denote the passed array that is not changed within the function. The second parameter shall have the type `size_t`.

The function returns the index of the maximum element of the passed array.

Here is the function definition.

```
size_t findLargest( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n <  2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t n1 = 1 + findLargest( a + 1, n - 1 );
        return a[0] < a[n1] ? n1 : 0;
    }
}
```

To reduce the number of recursive calls of the function you can split the passed array into two parts and call the function for each part.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

size_t findLargest( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t n1 = findLargest( a, n / 2 );
        size_t n2 = n / 2 + findLargest( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 );
        
        return a[n1] < a[n2] ? n2 : n1;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): " );
        
        size_t n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        int a[n];
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a[i] = rand() % ( 2 * n );
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        printf( "The largest element of the array is: %d\n", a[findLargest( a, n )] );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 10
5 14 0 4 19 8 2 1 11 6 
The largest element of the array is: 19
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 9
9 3 12 15 4 13 17 13 7 
The largest element of the array is: 17
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 8
2 13 9 11 12 8 14 3 
The largest element of the array is: 14
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 7
13 5 0 2 8 6 1 
The largest element of the array is: 13
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 6
10 7 11 5 1 7 
The largest element of the array is: 11
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 5
9 0 4 1 1 
The largest element of the array is: 9
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 4
2 0 6 5 
The largest element of the array is: 6
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 3
1 1 2 
The largest element of the array is: 2
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 2
1 0 
The largest element of the array is: 1
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 1
0 
The largest element of the array is: 0
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 0
```

Below there is shown how such a general recursive function that can be called for an array of any type can look

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

size_t findLargest( const void *base, 
                    size_t nmemb, 
                    size_t size, 
                    int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    if ( nmemb < 2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t nmemb1 = findLargest( base, nmemb / 2, size, cmp );
        size_t nmemb2 = nmemb / 2 + 
                        findLargest( ( const char * )base + nmemb / 2 * size, 
                                     nmemb - nmemb / 2, size, cmp );
        
        return cmp( ( const char * )base + nmemb1 * size, 
                    ( const char * )base + nmemb2 * size ) < 0
               ? nmemb2 : nmemb1;
    }
}

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    int left  = *( const int * )a;
    int right = *( const int * )b;
    
    return ( right < left ) - ( left < right );
}

int main(void) 
{
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): " );
        
        size_t n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        int a[n];
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a[i] = rand() % ( 2 * n );
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        size_t i = findLargest( a, n, sizeof( *a ), cmp );
        printf( "The largest element of the array is: %d\n", a[i] );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output might be

```
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 10
6 2 5 5 3 1 4 1 10 9 
The largest element of the array is: 10
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 9
9 7 1 11 5 16 8 2 8 
The largest element of the array is: 16
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 8
4 8 1 0 10 15 9 1 
The largest element of the array is: 15
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 7
13 0 4 9 3 4 4 
The largest element of the array is: 13
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 6
10 1 0 6 2 2 
The largest element of the array is: 10
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 5
5 4 3 4 5 
The largest element of the array is: 5
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array 4
(0 - exit): 3 4 3 5 
The largest element of the array is: 5
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 3
0 5 5 
The largest element of the array is: 5
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 2
0 0 
The largest element of the array is: 0
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 1
0 
The largest element of the array is: 0
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return some value in the recursive function and pass variables by reference in the parameter.
`int findLargest(int n, int arr[])`

Passing a variable by value won't alter the original value of variables (here largest), it just creates a new copy of that variable and assigns value to it.
The following code works fine

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int findLargest(int[], int, int);

    int main(){
   

     int n;
        int largest;
        int i;
    
        printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int arr[n];
        printf("Input %d elements in the array: \n", n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("element - %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
    
        if (n == 0){
            printf("Empty list\n");
        }

    else{
        largest = arr[0];
        largest = findLargest(arr, n - 1, largest);
        printf("\nThe largest number in the list is: %d\n", largest);
    }
}

int findLargest(int arr[], int position, int largest){
    if (position == 0)
        return largest;
    if (position > 0){
        if (arr[position] > largest){
            largest = arr[position];
        }
        return findLargest(arr, position - 1, largest);
    }
}
```